# Getting static map from Mapbox with maki icons that have - in their icon name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am trying to get a snapshot of the Mapbox map by using the static map api

https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-a-static-map-from-a-style

But if the icon name of the Maki icon of a marker has a - in between, i get the error

```
message: "Marker symbol "bicycle-share" is invalid."
```

Any idea how to resolve this? bicycle-share is a valid Maki icon.

Mapbox hasnt responded to my query yet.

Comment: Could you add the details of the payload you are sending to the API ?

Comment: I need not send any payload, just need to add the map and marker attributes to the api {name}-{label}+{color}({lon},{lat})

Comment: Probably try replacing `-` with `%2D` instead. Just encoding unsafe ASCII in a URL.

Comment: @bitsapien the api docs says only alpha numeric characters are allowed

Answer (score 1):

I am able to make this request including the `bicycle-share` icon:

`curl 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v10/static/pin-l-bicycle-share+4264fb(-87.0186,32.4055)/-87.0186,32.4055,14/70x70?access_token={YOUR_TOKEN}' --output example-mapbox-static-overlay-marker-pin-l-bicycle-share.png`

and the API successfully returns a map image with the icon on the marker:

[image: mapbox map with a bicycle icon on marker]

---

- Official docs: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#marker
- Replace `{YOUR_TOKEN}` with your free token: https://account.mapbox.com

---